# WPF+REST+EF: what is the best way to organize DTO's?

Tags: json, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a WPF MVVM app with 3 layers:

1. UI
2. Services
3. DAL

and some item, for example Order. I need 3 DTO:

1. Class for MVVM layer, with PropertyChanged notification;
2. Class for Json deserializer (get objects by REST API)
3. Class for Entity Framework (cache data in DB).

Well, I can use ONE class for all three cases, but this will be mix of different attributes (from EF, JSon, MVVM) and excess dependencies of layers.

Another way: make 3 classes, each layer has own class, and use AutoMapper for fast convert between. No bad, but 3 almost identical (90%) copy of each DTO class... not elegant solution.

What is the best approach? What do you use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best approach? What do you use?

The second approach, i.e. you define your business objects in a separate assembly that you can reference from all your applications. These classes should not implement any client-specific interfaces such as INotifyPropertyChanged but be pure POCO classes that contains business logic only.

In your WPF application, you then create a view model class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and wraps any properties of the business object that it makes sense to expose to and bind to from the view.

The view model then has a reference to the model and the view binds to the view model. This is typically how the MVVM design pattern is (or should be) implemented in a WPF application. The view model class contains your application logic, for example how to notify the view when a data bound property value is changed, and the model contains the business logic that is the same across all platforms and applications.

Of course this means that you will end up with a larger number of classes in total but this is not necessarily a bad thing as each class has its own responsibility.

The responsibility of a view model is to act as a model for the application specific XAML view whereas the responsibility of the model class is to implement the business logic and the responsibility of the DTO class is to simply transfer the data between the different tiers. This is a far better solution - at least in my opinion and probably in most enterprise architect's opinions as well - than defining a single class that implements all kind of UI specific logic just for the sake of reducing the number of classes.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to implement layered WPF app, and one problem I have on my way. Imagine, there is two layers: UI and DAL, DAL has Entity Frameworl CE (via NuGet), UI has reference to DAL project. It doesn't work, error about "No providers found", I've found soultion: add EF via NuGet to UI layer to. It works now, but how I can remove this dependency?

Comment: If the layers live in the same process you might have to reference Entity Framework to be able to define a valid connection string. In an enterprise N-tier architecture the DAL is typically located on another computer though and then you don't define the connection string to the database in the client app as the client app only knows about a service that connects to the database using the DAL.